# How to use locals in child modules in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-modules

I've locals.tf in root module and want to use it to child modules. Directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── env.tfvars
├── local.tf
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── alb
│   │   ├── alb.tf
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   └── variable.tf
│   ├── ecr
│   │   ├── ecr.tf
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   └── variable.tf
│   ├── ecs
│   │   ├── ecs.tf
│   │   └── variable.tf
```

local.tf

```
locals {
  customer_env = "${var.customer_name}-${var.env}"
}
```

Wanted to use this locals into child modules.

modules/ecs/ecs.tf

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = "${local.customer_env}"
  tags = {
   Environment = var.env
  }
}
```

Tried that way but throwing an error

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared local value
│
│   on modules/ecs/ecs.tf line 2, in resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main":
│    2:   name = "${local.customer_env}"
│
│ A local value with the name "customer_env" has not been declared.
╵
```

Answer (score 4):

Child modules **do not inherit** variables and locals from the parent module. You have to explicitly pass them in. So, for example for your `ecs` module you have pass the local in:

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "./modules/ecs"
  customer_env = local.customer_env
}
```

Obviously in the `ecs` module you have to have the corresponding variable:

```
variable "customer_env" {}
```

And the `aws_ecs_cluster.main` will use the variable:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = var.customer_env
  tags = {
   Environment = var.env
  }
}
```

You have to do it for all your modules.